# SQL concat select count and varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, concatenation

I am currently combining `SELECT COUNT (column)` on a user-defined function with `varchar` like so:

```
'Express 24: ' + (SELECT COUNT(Product) FROM [DHL].[dbo].[F_SubBetsy](@startdate, @enddate, 'EXPRESS EXPRESS 24', @contract, @account)) +
'\r\nExpress 48: ' + (SEL...
```

I'm getting the error:

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Express 24: ' to data type int.*

Presumably `SELECT COUNT` is returning an `int` and `varchar` is less desired than an int, but despite several attempts, I haven't figured out how to combine `CAST( AS NVARCHAR())` or `VARCHAR()` with SELECT COUNT properly.

Can someone solve this for me?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'Express 24: ' + CAST(
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(Product) 
    FROM    [DHL].[dbo].[F_SubBetsy](@startdate, @enddate, 
                                    'EXPRESS EXPRESS 24', @contract, @account) 
    ) as varchar(16)) +
'\r\nExpress 48: ' + (SEL...
```

Comment: Works great, dunno why you need to wrap the thing with extra brackets, but thanks :D

Comment: The extra parentheses evaluate the SQL query.  So `(select 1)` is a single row containing a single column.  But `select 1` is a query, which is not allowed as a parameter to `cast`.